# Forcing C to make an out of bound error and crash

Tags: c, error-handling

I know it is a weird question but I am making a function, that should crash the program and send an error. What I have done done is divided by zero, that gives a "floating point error".

Is there a way to force C to give an error like "Index out of bound" or somthing like that? - or is the best suited error a "segmentation fault" with some pointer magic?

```
int a = 10/0;       //Floating point error
//int *p = (int *)0;  //Segmentation fault
```

EDIT:
Segmentation fault was caused by another thing!

Comment: Linux? Windows? MacOS?

Comment: _only_ `int *p = (int *)0;` gave you segfault?

Comment: What do you mean by "best suited error"? Best suited for what?

Comment: @alain: For "index out of bounds"

Comment: @SouravGhosh No. You are right. It is another thing in the program that gives that.

Comment: There is no "index out of bounds" exception in C like in Java. The exceptions are platform-specific.

Comment: C does not make any guarantees about such faults. It is all _**undefined** behaviour_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UNIX based operating systems most of the errors are represented as signals. You can send yourself a signal and it will be interpreted by the application and O/S as that event having happened.

So to emulate a seg fault from a function you can do:

```
#include <signal.h>

raise(SIGSEGV);
```

You could simulate other errors in the same way, such as SIGFPE for a floating point exception, SIGSYS for a bad system call etc.

Comment: Thank you. This is as clean as it gets.